# Laravel pagination - error 404 - I can't find content on the second page

Tags: html, database, laravel, pagination

I just installed pagination on my page, but when I press on page 2, I get `error 404, Page not found`. Do you know what's wrong in my code? For the moment, I have a limit for 6 posts, and I need to display the rest of posts on the second, third etc pages.
**Here is the link:**
`https://website.com/topic/foreign%20languages/career-solutions?page=2`

**Here is my route :**

```php
Route::any('/topic/{category?}/career-solutions/{page?}', 'CategoryController@searchCareer' );
```

**Here is my controller:**

```php
public function searchCareer()
{
    $data = $this->data;
    $c = Input::get ( 'c' );
    $d = Input::get ( 'd' );
    $category = Category::find($c)->with('event','news','opinion')->firstOrFail();
    $q = Input::get ( 'q' );

    $user = CareerSolution::where ( 'subject', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )
        ->where('career_solutions.topic_category_id', '=', $c)
        ->join('role_users' , 'role_users.user_id', '=', 'career_solutions.user_id')
        ->join('roles' , 'roles.id', '=', 'role_users.role_id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'career_solutions.user_id')
        ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'career_solutions.topic_category_id')
        ->orWhere ( 'career_solutions.user_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )
        ->orWhere ( 'career_solutions.id', '=', 'events.subject')
        ->orWhere('career_solutions.topic_category_id' ,'=', $category->id)
        ->orWhere ( 'career_solutions.user_id', '=', 'users.username')
        ->select('career_solutions.id as id','subject','users.id as user_id','username', 'profile_picture', 'role_id', 'optional', 'topic_category_id','categories.category')
        ->paginate(6);

    $data['sub_category'] = \App\CareerSolutionCategory::where('parent_id', '=' ,$c)->withCount('career_solution')->get();
    $data['test'] = 'view-career-solutions';
    $data['link'] = 'search-career-solutions';
    $data['type'] = 'Career Solution';
    $data['typee'] = 'briefcase fa-';
    $topic_id = CareerSolution::select('id', 'subject')
        ->get();

    if (count ( $user ) > 0) {
        return view('category-search', $data)
            ->withDetails($user)
            ->withQuery($q)
            ->with(compact('topic_id'))
            ->with(compact('account'))
            ->with(compact('category'))
            ->with(compact('c'))
            ->with(compact('d'));
    } else {
        return view('category-search', $data)
            ->withMessage('No Details found. Try to search again !');
    }
}
```

**My view:**

```
@foreach($details as $user)
// content
@endforeach
{!! $details->render() !!}
```

Comment: page is a request parameter, it's useless writing it inside the route, and i'm not sure, but maybe it can be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is inside the Route directive... you declare the route in this way

```php
Route::any('/topic/{category?}/career-solutions/{page?}', 'CategoryController@searchCareer' );
```

but this is valid for request like `https://website.com/topic/foreign%20languages/career-solutions/2` and not for `https://website.com/topic/foreign%20languages/career-solutions?page=2`, so i think that you should change your route to

```
Route::any('/topic/{category?}/career-solutions', 'CategoryController@searchCareer' );
```

Pagination will search automatically in the request if the page param is set or not, there is no use to declare it on the route

Comment: the first page load with no problem? have you deleted cache inside boostrap/cache?

Comment: Sure, the first page is loading with no problem. I used an incognito page to test it .

Comment: please, post the link for the first page, and than the link that you get when you press ''page 2''

Comment: First link : `https://website.com/topic/foreign%20languages/career-solutions` second : `https://website.com/topic/foreign%20languages/career-solutions?page=2`

Comment: try to add inside the method searchCareer "dd("try");" in the beginning, and than navigate to `https://website.com/topic/foreign%20languages/career-solutions?page=2` ... i belive it's not a paginate problem, but a laravel route pattern matching problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202339/discussion-between-andrew-and-albertosinigaglia).