# Laravel pagination link leads to 404 page

Tags: laravel

(Edit: i added a gif here to demonstrate the problem: https://ibb.co/HKnm82n )Only the first page is loaded in, oddly the link button that should've led the user to the next page would display a 404 not found error, i do not know how or why this is the case. the other pagination i have works perfectly fine.

Edit: I forgot to share the link as well, so here it is:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/search?page=2

Heres the route from web.php
`Route::post('/profile/search', [ProfilesController::class, 'search'])->name('profile.search');`

This one is the search method from ProfilesController:

```
public function search()
    {
        $validated = request()->validate([       //Validate requests
            'search_input' => 'string',
            'search_by' => '',
        ]);

        if($validated['search_by'] === 'username')     //the user requests to search by username?
        {
            //Paginate by 5
            $users = User::where('username', 'LIKE', '%'.$validated['search_input'].'%')->paginate(5);
            
            return view('profiles.search', compact('users'));
        }

        else
        {

            return redirect(route('profile.show', $validated['search_input']));
        }
        
    }
```

And this here is a snippet of profiles.search view:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
                        <td><img class="rounded-circle" style="max-width: 80px" src="/storage/{{ $user->profile->profile_picture ?? 'defaults/placeholder_pfp.png' }}" alt="pfp"></td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="text-dark" href="{{ route('profile.show', $user->id) }}">
                                <b>{{ $user->username }}</b>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
</table>
            {{ $users->links() }}
```

I tried:

- Manually setting the pagination path to the route path
- Changing the POST method to GET
- Switching the order of the route in web.php
- Adding an optional variable to the path of the route
- I've also read through this discussion, but it didnt really get through my head -> [Laravel pagination - error 404 - I can't find content on the second page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58857434/laravel-pagination-error-404-i-cant-find-content-on-the-second-page)

Comment: Where do you use `{{ $users->links() }}`?

Comment: Your code will only work - **in your case** - for pagination if `search_by` is set to `"username"`. Therefore, your URL is correct when it looks like this: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/search?page=2&search_by=username`. In the absence of this, I can imagine that the redirection in the 'else' branch occurs, where it either does not exist or the route throws an error. First, use native solutions as `$users->withQueryString()->links()` to generate correctly links. After this can try manually call with example urls.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to include the $users->links(), its there now

Comment: i did as you described, i manually entered this url into the browser after clicking the corrected link: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/search?page=2&search_by=username`. but im afraid it still returns 404.

Comment: Your first statement is correct, only that the else statement would assume that the user had entered an ID instead of a username therefore it will redirect the user to the profile that holds that ID, but if it doesn't exist it'll return a 404 as per usual.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're paginating the results of username searches. If that's the case, you should append the required query strings for your next page like this:

```
$users->appends(['search_input' => $validated['search_input']]);
```

Comment: this is the link after i added those in: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/search?search_input=J&page=2`. Unfortunately, the issue still persists.

Comment: did you try to add search_by to the appends?